# What iOS apps read health records from Apple Health?

Tags: health.app, health-kit

Apple's website says that "[third-party apps can request access to your health records](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/download-health-records-iphe103f5a3e/ios)" but I can't find any apps in the app store that read them. Are there any apps that read health records (e.g., allergies, medications, or immunizations, lab results, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an app that appears to match: [ClinicQ](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/clinic-q/id1342823958) by Health Here.

The fourth screenshot on the AppStore claims:

> CliniQ can import your allergies, medical conditions, procedures and medications from Apple Health

[image: Screenshot from AppStore]

In the process, I found how to [add an institution](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208680) as a data source (Apple Health can pull records from a compatible portal) although this is not yet enabled in Australia, probably because currently only US, UK and Canada have [participating sources](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208647).

I also learned the difference between Health Records and the older [Clinical Documents](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/aavhvm/apple_health_records_vs_apple_clinical_documents/).

Finding apps that DO NOT access Health Records was quite easy.  For Aussies, the [Healthi](https://apps.apple.com/au/app/healthi/id1148880324) app can connect to [MyHealthRecord](https://www.myhealthrecord.gov.au) records, but doesn't integrate with Apple's Health app.

Around launch time (2018), [A tale of two hospitals](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3268467/a-tale-of-two-hospitals-that-adopted-apples-health-record-app.html) mentions Johns Hopkins and Penn Medicine as early adopters.  The same article mentions 'EMR vendors such as EPIC, Cerner, Athenahealth, Meditech and AllScripts'... these are potential sources for more examples of apps that DO use the Health Records.

Answer (score -2):

As shown in [Apple's official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkclinicaltypeidentifier), it is completely possible for an app to request permission to read these. However, as Apple suggests, apps will only request this data if they need to, especially with Apple's new privacy labels.

I don't see the purpose of searching for an app for the sole reason that it uses these, but you may want to check out the apps of health databases or of medical companies.